# How does Magento create dynamic functions?

Tags: php, magento

Can anyone tell me how Magento creates dynamic functions? For example for product info, we call:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(29);
```

`$product->getData()` return all the data in array format. But we can fetch the same information from the individual functions like:

```
$product->getSkuId()
$product->getProdId()
$product->getName()
```

Can anyone tell me that how Magento creates these dynamic functions?

Comment: I am not familiar with Magento but have you looked at the source code?

Comment: The source code is too big and the folder structure of Magento is too complicated. So I can't. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento is using [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) magic method. When you try to call a method which is really does not exists with that class and if you have defined `__call` method in your class, The `__call` method is called and Magento take the name of actual requested method and call the another method which handles this request to fetch particular thing for you.

**EDIT**

All the Model classes are inherited from the `Varien_Object` class see [diagram](http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d58/class_varien___object.html)  and the magic methods like `__get`, `__set` and `__call` are defined here in the `Varien_Object` class and will be used by the classes which are inherited by `Varien_Object` class. You can find this class here `/magento_installation_diretctory/lib/Varien/Object.php`.

view the source code of Varien_Object class.

Comment: Can you tell me the name of file where Magento call getName() or getSKU() functions?

Comment: @munjal: Ok, added more details.

Answer (score 1):

probably by using [__call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)